# What is an "implementation plan"?

Tags: documentation

I was recently given the task of creating an implementation plan document.  When I asked for an example of one that I could look at, I was told to look at the Project Plan that had already been created an use that as a base.  I'm still a bit confused on what I should be creating.  Can anyone point me to a good example out there or to something that explains what this is and details about what it should contain.

Answer (score 5):

Implementation = Deployment in most of the companies I have worked with. We include the following sections in our current template:

- BRIEF DESCRIPTION | What is Covered in this Deployment Plan?
- OBJECTIVES | What Needs to be Accomplished?
- SUCCESS CRITERIA | How Will Others See We have Succeeded?
- POLICY/PROCESS | Are there Policies and Processes?
- ORGANIZATION | Who is Involved in this Deployment?
- DISTRIBUTION | How do you Plan to Distribute the Solution / Application?
- CHECK READINESS | Is the Infrastructure ready for the Deployment?
- SUPPORT | How Will You Prepare the Support Team?
- TRAINING | To Whom and How Will You Provide the Training?
- PILOT PHASE | Limited Deployment
- COMMUNICATION | Identify all Communication Vehicles
- SCHEDULE | Project Estimated Effort/Duration
- RISK ANALYSIS | What Could Go Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation plan specifies how to implement the software.  If you are installing into a corporate data center, you should work with team that will be operating the software.

Take care to ensure you are following existing standard for deployment locations.  On UNIX/Linux there is `hier` document which explains what should go where in the directories.  Windows has similar standards.

If the implementation is to multiple servers, the implementation plan becomes more complex. It can also introduce issues of which components need to be deployed when.  On upgrades this may introduce version incompatibility issues.

Whatever platform(s) the implementation will target, prerequisites should be documented.  Try to state minimum versions rather than specific versions.  (This will allow important security updates to be applied.)   This may require code changes if specific versions are checked for in the software.

@SBWorks has provided a good list of sections to consider.  Depending on the the implementation some sections may not be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, its a more detailed plan about the installing of software/hardware with respect to making the project live (although there may be a development and various test system rollout imp plans too). A backout plan is almost always a required sibling to the imp plan.

Project Plan will help, but is likley to be to high level. You will need to look for any earlier releases (or similar releases if none exist or the topology is significantly changed), the operation team that will be using the live project, capacity planning (if you have one), any harward/database/etc teams if relevent. It is something that you should really be mentored through first time - perhaps grab the lead analyst or architect on your project for some help - chances are they will have something that you can modify.

//Edit: Typo